# Capital in Bibtex

Tags: latex, bibtex

I want to show some letters in Bibliography as capital. For example:

```
@misc{libsvm,  
abstract = {LIBSVM is an implbmentation of Support vector machine (SVM).},  
author = {Chang, Chih-Chung},  
howpublished = {\url{http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/}},  
keywords = {svm},  
posted-at = {2010-04-08 00:05:04},  
priority = {2},  
title = {LIBSVM.},  
url = "http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/",  
year = {2008}  
}
```

But "LIBSVM" is not shown as it is:

> [3] Chih-Chung Chang. Libsvm. http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/ ̃cjlin/libsvm/,
>       2008.

How can I make the letters capital? Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Generally, to keep BibTeX from turning your letters lowercase, enclose them in `{}`:

```
title = {A History Of {StudlyCaps}}
```

will produce "A history of StudlyCaps."

Alceu Costa is correct that all-capital abbreviations should be formatted in small capitals, but that is a different matter than this.

Comment: As a general hygiene rule, only escape proper names and acronyms in this way: the reason why Bibtex changes case in this way is that some bibliographic styles will uppercase and some lowercase titles.  Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897728/a-bib-style-to-capitalize-book-titles-but-not-paper-titles/1920968#1920968

Answer (score 4):

The `\textsc` is used to format the text in small capitals. You can do this in your .bib file:

```
title = {\textsc{LIBSVM}}
```

Comment: Thanks, Alceu! So if I want to make "Library of Support Vector Machine", I have to put L, S, V and M into \textsc{} repspectively? Is there a way to do it just once?

Answer (score 3):

Place {} brackets around anything you want to keep in CAPS.

For example:

```
@type{bibkey,

  title = "{M}y {B}ibliography is the {B}est!",

  author = "{ABCDE}", 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of **IEEEtran LaTeX Class** template, one can simply do the following:

```
title = "{3D Open Source Framework for Something you need}"
```

A template can be found at the following link

http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html