# Repair .bib file titles through Regex

Tags: python, regex, latex

After preparing my LaTeX bibliography in .bib file, I discovered that there's an issue with capitalisation.

According to: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800527/preserving-all-capitalization-in-bibtex) information, solution is to add brackets to each word in each title (as I checked, add brackets to whole title doesn't work).

For example, I wish to change *from*:

```
title   = "What a interesting title",
title= "What a boring title",
title="What a crazy title",
```

*to:*

```
title   = "{What} {a} {interesting} {title}",
title= "{What} {a} {boring} {title}",
title="{What} {a} {crazy} {title}",
```

so:

```
title <any number of spaces> = <any number of spaces> " <words in title> ",
```

should be replaced by:

```
title <any number of spaces> = <any number of spaces> " <{Each} {word} {in} {title} {should} {be} {in} {bracket}> ",
```

---

I'm trying to do that by Regex in Python but have no idea what is wrong.

My code:

```
re.sub(r'(title[\s-]*=[\s-]*\")(\b(\w+)\b)',r'\1{\2}',line)
```

add brackets to the first word only.

Comment: did you have any problem with `regex` module?

Comment: I guess that something is wrong within my regex pattern especially in (\b(\w+)\b), but I don't understand what/how to correct this.

Comment: What's your expected output for this `title   = "What a interesting title BAR:foo", barfoo` input?

Comment: @AvinashRaj that input is invalid for LaTeK so it isn't relevant. matandked is talking about setting values for `title`, don't lose sight of that.

Comment: is this because of the string after comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses negative lookahead on the first part of the string:

```
>>> import re
... s = """title   = "It's an interesting title",
... title= "What a boring title",
... title="What a crazy title","""
... print(re.sub(r'(?!title\s*=\s*")\b(\S+)\b',r'{\1}',s))
title   = "{It's} {an} {interesting} {title}",
title= "{What} {a} {boring} {title}",
title="{What} {a} {crazy} {title}",
```

See http://regex101.com/r/hL2lE6/6

Update: Avinash Raj made a good point about special characters that could appear in titles, like apostrophes, so I changed `\w+` to `\S+` and updated the example text to test it.

Note: If your titles include words ending with a special character and that character needs to be included in the brackets, see here for a solution: http://regex101.com/r/hL2lE6/11

It uses `(?!title\s*=\s*")\b([^"=\s]+)`. But, your main concern was capitalization so it may not matter. In that case I recommend keeping it simple and sticking with `\S+`.

Answer (score 0):

It couldn't be possible through  `re` module. But you could achieve this through external `regex` module like below.

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = '''title   = "What a interesting title",
title= "What a boring title",
title="What a crazy title",'''
>>> print(regex.sub(r'(?m)((?:^title\s*=\s*"|\G) *)([^"\s\n]+)', r'\1{\2}',s))
title   = "{What} {a} {interesting} {title}",
title= "{What} {a} {boring} {title}",
title="{What} {a} {crazy} {title}",
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jL4eP9/2)

`\G` assert position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match. `\G` forces the pattern to only return matches that are part of a continuous chain of matches.

References:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html
- [What is the use of '\G' anchor in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897949/what-is-the-use-of-g-anchor-in-regex)

Comment: Thanks, both answers are very helpful. I forgot to mention that I need to add brackets *only* to lines which contains "title" string. But I will do that by simply checking if "title" in line: